# How to optimize flipping through 50+ images, which are downloaded

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, optimization, nsurlconnection

I have an iPad app with about 50+ full screen images(png) and I want to be able to flip back and forward between the images. To make the app size smaller I am downloading the images as I need them, using NSURLConnection. I also cache about 15 images. The problem I am running into is that even though I have a cache it is quite easy to flip through the cache and to an image that has not been downloaded yet.

I am wondering what suggestion you have to fix my problem. Should I just increase the cache or should I down res the images? Do I have to limit the number of images I am downloading at the same time? Many thanks!

This is how I start each image download

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:[NSURLRequest 
            requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrlString]] 
            delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

[conn scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]
            forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

[conn start];
```

Comment: Do you know how many images there are in total before you start the image display? (You could simply display a place-holder image in each of the slots until the NSURLConnection provides the necessary.) That said, caching the images within your apps document directory when they've downloaded shouldn't cause any issues I'd have thought. (It's not *that* much data all things considered.)

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the flipping through the photos once they have been downloaded, here are a few tips to try.

- Have both a low resolution and a high resolution version of the photo available.
- Whenever you have one picture loaded, bring the highres versions of its immediate neighbors into memory.  In otherwords, load, but don't display those pictures.
- Load the low resolution images into memory of some range surrounding the displayed picture.  So if picture 5 is displayed, and your range is 5, load lowres pictures 0 through 10
- While a user is flipping through, render the low resolution first, and then load the high resolution picture.

These tips should account for a user flipping through a few pictures to find the desired photo, and then pausing on a select picture, and then flipping through some more.

Comment: amccormack Thanks of your suggestion.